# Comparing timevalues with other rows in table in a condition

Tags: pandas

this is a cross post from my SQL attempts on here:
[Comparing with other rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025477/comparing-with-other-rows-in-table)

So I tried, but it didn't work:

```
df3[df3['activity_date']>=df2['activity_date']+pd.to_timedelta(59,unit='d')]
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
anon_id|signup_date|activity_date|
__________________________________
123    |01-01-2019 |02-01-2019   | 
123    |01-01-2019 |02-02-2019   | 
123    |01-01-2019 |02-03-2019   | 
123    |01-01-2019 |02-04-2019   |
```

WANTED:

```
anon_id|signup_date|activity_date| active
__________________________________
123    |01-01-2019 |02-01-2019   | yes
123    |01-01-2019 |02-02-2019   | yes
123    |01-01-2019 |02-03-2019   | no
123    |01-01-2019 |02-04-2019   | no
```

Active is a column that is populated with a Boolean value if there is another occurrence of same **anon_id**, *within 60 days* of the **activity_date** of that row. Someone help me make this pandas column ?